# JPA hibernate one to many infinite loop bidirectional relation problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a bidirectional relation between two tables using JAP (`@Entity`). when I do my Select throw `repository.findAll()` it returns to me an infinite loop of an object inside the other and others inside it.

here first entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS_IDENTIDAD")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoId", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoId = :tidoId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoDescripcion", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoDescripcion = :tidoDescripcion"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoSiglas", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoSiglas = :tidoSiglas")})
public class TiposDocumentosIdentidad implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "TIDO_TIDO_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "TIDO_ID")
    private Integer tidoId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TIDO_DESCRIPCION")
    private String tidoDescripcion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TIDO_SIGLAS")
    private String tidoSiglas;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tidoId")
    private Collection<Personas> personasCollection;
.
.
@XmlTransient
    public Collection<Personas> getPersonasCollection() {
        return personasCollection;
    }

    public void setPersonasCollection(Collection<Personas> personasCollection) {
        this.personasCollection = personasCollection;
    }
.
.
```

sencond entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONAS")
@XmlRootElement

public class Person as implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "PERSONAS_PERS_ID_SEQ")
@Column(name = "PERS_ID")
private Integer persId;
@Column(name = "PERS_DIGITO_VERIFICACION")
private String persDigitoVerificacion;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "PERS_NUMERO_DOCUMENTO")
private String persNumeroDocumento;    
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "PERS_FECHA_CREACION")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date persFechaCreacion;
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    persFechaCreacion = new Date();
}

@JoinColumn(name = "TIDO_ID", referencedColumnName = "TIDO_ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)    
private TiposDocumentosIdentidad tidoId;
.
.
.
```

here is the pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>co.com.personasProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>personasProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>personasProject</name>
    <description></description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the infinite result
[image]

How can I solve this error? I just have q row int both tables

Comment: Are you using Jackson? It seems you are retuning JSON, then why `@XmlRootElement`?

Comment: @JoãoDias I don´t konw what Jackson is. but you can see I dont use anything call Jackson in the pom. i go to see that to see if this make the error

Comment: You don't need to explicitly add Jackson in your `pom.xml`. `spring-boot-starter-web` has it as a transitive dependency. Jackson allows you to serialize or map java objects to JSON and vice versa (that is why you see your response as JSON). Please try my answer below and check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try annotating the relationship with `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference` to allow Jackson to better handle the bi-directional relationship:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS_IDENTIDAD")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoId", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoId = :tidoId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoDescripcion", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoDescripcion = :tidoDescripcion"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoSiglas", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoSiglas = :tidoSiglas")})
public class TiposDocumentosIdentidad implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "TIDO_TIDO_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "TIDO_ID")
    private Integer tidoId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TIDO_DESCRIPCION")
    private String tidoDescripcion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TIDO_SIGLAS")
    private String tidoSiglas;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tidoId")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<Personas> personasCollection;
.
.
    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Personas> getPersonasCollection() {
        return personasCollection;
    }

    public void setPersonasCollection(Collection<Personas> personasCollection) {
        this.personasCollection = personasCollection;
    }
.
.
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONAS")
@XmlRootElement

public class Person as implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "PERSONAS_PERS_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "PERS_ID")
    private Integer persId;
    @Column(name = "PERS_DIGITO_VERIFICACION")
    private String persDigitoVerificacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PERS_NUMERO_DOCUMENTO")
    private String persNumeroDocumento;    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PERS_FECHA_CREACION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date persFechaCreacion;
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        persFechaCreacion = new Date();
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "TIDO_ID", referencedColumnName = "TIDO_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private TiposDocumentosIdentidad tidoId;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This should fix it assuming you are using Jackson to serialize to JSON. You can read more at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion.

---

Another option would be using `@JsonIdentityInfo` as follows (it also requires Jackson):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS_IDENTIDAD")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "tidoId")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoId", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoId = :tidoId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoDescripcion", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoDescripcion = :tidoDescripcion"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TiposDocumentosIdentidad.findByTidoSiglas", query = "SELECT t FROM TiposDocumentosIdentidad t WHERE t.tidoSiglas = :tidoSiglas")})
public class TiposDocumentosIdentidad implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "TIDO_TIDO_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "TIDO_ID")
    private Integer tidoId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TIDO_DESCRIPCION")
    private String tidoDescripcion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TIDO_SIGLAS")
    private String tidoSiglas;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tidoId")
    private Collection<Personas> personasCollection;
.
.
    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Personas> getPersonasCollection() {
        return personasCollection;
    }

    public void setPersonasCollection(Collection<Personas> personasCollection) {
        this.personasCollection = personasCollection;
    }
.
.
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONAS")
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "persId")
public class Person as implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "PERSONAS_PERS_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "PERS_ID")
    private Integer persId;
    @Column(name = "PERS_DIGITO_VERIFICACION")
    private String persDigitoVerificacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PERS_NUMERO_DOCUMENTO")
    private String persNumeroDocumento;    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PERS_FECHA_CREACION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date persFechaCreacion;
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        persFechaCreacion = new Date();
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "TIDO_ID", referencedColumnName = "TIDO_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private TiposDocumentosIdentidad tidoId;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: i tried to thins. one I delete the @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tidoId")
    private Collection<Personas> personasCollection; And it work but I I wont bi able to Consult the person that have a spesified TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS_IDENTIDAD cus I dont have the relation from here.

Comment: Have you tried my proposed solution?

Comment: Hi @JoãoDias ​I tried two things. one I delete the @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tidoId")
   ​private Collection<Personas> personasCollection; And it work but I I wont be able to Consult the person that have a spesified TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS_IDENTIDAD cus I dont have the relation from here.
Second I add what you said and the jackson dependecie but it bring to me onli the data of the PERSONAS entity, it dont bring to me the TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS_IDENTIDAD  that the person have.  thanks fotr anskwer I go to wait  your comment and if we can review the code it will be great..

Comment: @DiegoIzquierdoDussan, I've added another option with `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation, please check it ;)

Comment: thanks @JoãoDias but just show infinite look but without tipo documento info like a loop of the person. I had to del the relation in tipo documento class to continue